# Regular Expression to find all occurrences of a word within a lookaround expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to find all occurrences of "st" within any class declaration on any html page like this for example:

```
class="st0 st1 st2", class="st3 st45", class="st678"
```

I say within a class declararion because there may be other occurrences of "st" throughout the document and I do not want to change every occurrence.

My ultimate goal here is a find and replace. I have the logic written out for that but I just need to figure out how to isolate "st" from the string.

I have experimented with a few different lookaround expressions but I cannot seem to match every occurrence. Below are a few examples of what I have been trying.

**This expression gets everything between 'class="' and '"':**

Regular Expression:

```
(?<=class=").*(?=")
```

Test sting:

```
class="st10 st11"
```

Matching result :

```
"st10 st11"
```

**Here is another one I tried:**

Regular Expression:

```
(?<=class=")((st)\d*\s*)*(?=")
```

Test sting:

```
class="st10 st11"
```

Matching result:

```
"st10 st11"
```

Matching groups:

1. st11
2. st

I have been testing my regular expression here at [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com)

<sub>added from comments</sub>
I am going to be using the regular expression within a terminal shell command which I will run on a specific folder. The shell command will do a find and replace on every file that is in the folder like this...

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/st/stx/g;' ~/Desktop/svg_find_replace/*.svg.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This could be done much more easily with a parser - if this is not an option [**`\bst\d+`**](https://regex101.com/r/aJ8cU8/1) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Exactly, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I am going to be using the regular expression within a terminal shell command which I will run on a specific folder. The shell command will do a find and replace on every file that is in the folder like this... perl -pi -w -e 's/st/stx/g;' ~/Desktop/svg_find_replace/*.svg.

Comment: @Jan tried `\bst\d+` with no matches. Modifed expression to this `(?<=class=")((\bst\d+)\s*)*(?=")` still the same match results. Seems that regular epressions don't quite work the same within lookaround expressions

Comment: please add your specific use case to your question, a good answer will be dependent on the tool you are using to do this replacement

Comment: for example, if you are using perl you should definitely not be trying to write a Ruby regex, as Ruby does not use PCRE while perl does

Comment: @WillBarnwell Hi. What I am really trying to do is write a regular expression that will find all occurrences of "st" on any class declaration within an html file. I will be using the expression in a shell script but at this point if I cannot get the expression working properly, I cannot move to the next step. So I had, first, written an expression that uses lookbefore `(?<=class=")` and lookafter `(?=")` to define the boundaries of where I want to search. So now I want to isolate all occurrences of "st". That is really it right now. I was using rubular.com to test the expression, that's all.

Comment: @WillBarnwell I am using this as my test string: `class="st0 st1 st2", class="st3 st45", class="st678"`

Comment: @WillBarnwell and this as my regular expression so far: `(?<=class=")((\bst\d+\s*)*)(?=")`

Comment: don't write these as comments, edit your post to add this information

Comment: PCRE is the regex language used by perl and sed and a bund of other shell tools, you should use something like https://regex101.com/ instead of Rubular, which is using a different regex language

Comment: You need to explain what exactly going to do and what tool you use as others mentioned. Maybe you can use a [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) based pattern [like this for Ruby](http://www.rubular.com/r/6Vl4mgXmfG) or something [like this for PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/wM4eJ8/1)

Comment: @WillBarnwell  Thanks for your comments. I have used both rubular and regex101 within the last hour or so with the same results, just to make sure that things are the same in both.

Comment: @masahs I edited your question, didn't see you comment before (: please check if ok. See if [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wM4eJ8/3) helps.

Comment: @bobblebubble I am just trying to figure out if I can get this regular expression working as a proof of concept and thought I'd reach out to the community for help. One of the earlier commenters had asked why I was not using a parser and I replied because I would be using the expression in a shell command so that is why i chose to use a regular expression... nothing more.

Comment: @bobblebubble - That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you so much for giving it a go.

Comment: @bobblebubble regular expressions are certainly not my strong suit. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @masahs you're welcome. Also can do without the lookbehind like this: [`(?:class="|\G(?!^))(?:(?!st)[^"])*\Kst`](https://regex101.com/r/nE1jH0/1) should I post answer if you need explanation?

Comment: @bobblebubble you should make that an answer

Comment: I forgot about \K, which is a serious regex ninja tool

Comment: @bobblebubble yes, make that an answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble - just tested the regular expression within my shell command and it worked flawlessly. Thanks.

Comment: @masha glad it's working for your needs (: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex based on [`\G` to chain matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

```
(?:class="|\G(?!^))(?:(?!st)[^"])*\Kst
```

- `(?:` opens a [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) for alternation.
- `(?:class="|\G(?!^))` the first part is to set where the match starts. `\G` would also match the beginning of the string. To prevent this the negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!^)` is used.
- `(?:(?!st)[^"])*` this part is to match any amount of characters that are [not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `"` and prevent skipping of `st` by use of a negative lookahead `(?!st)`
- [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match.

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nE1jH0/1). It is probably a rather advanced pattern. SO has a nice [regex faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).